# ZeroMQ: What are the possibilities of packet loss in PUSH/PULL method?

Tags: zeromq

I'm using ZeroMQ `PUSH/PULL` technique.

The `PUSH` socket blocks when no `PULL` sockets available.

What are the different scenarios in which there's packet loss and if possible, how can we tackle them?

Comment: I have mentioned one possibility in here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43869119/3273991

Comment: @NoName [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, `PUSH`-side access may block, but need not do so:

distributed systems' designs ought anticipate such state and rather use a nonblocking mode of the **`.send( payload, zmq.NOBLOCK )`** command.

Some other means are further available for a detailed configuration via **`.setsockopt( ... )`**

---

### Zero-compromise:

There is nothing as a packet-loss in the ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Pattern design. Either ZeroMQ delivers a complete message-payload, or nothing. There is zero alternative to this, so packet-loss does not match the set of ZeroMQ ideas & principles implemented under the hood. The **`.Context()`** instance is capable of saving most of the low level transport & signalisation situations and still re-connect lost abstract-socket transports & deliver the data or deliver nothing, Zero-Compromise on this.

---

### The best next step:

As the messaging landscape is rich of features and new design paradigms, the best next step is to learn more about the technology and about designing such distributed systems. May enjoy other ZeroMQ-related posts here and there linked [**pdf-book with many design issues and approaches to solutions** from Pieter HINTJENS himself. **Worth one's time to read it.**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)

Comment: I think he's talking about messages getting lost.

Comment: With all due respect, mis-directed messages ( actually by-design knowingly routed messages ) are **not "lost" messages**. Sure, there is a necessarity to cope with this in the ZeroMQ messaging / signalling infrastructure setup, but this does not relate to the "lost" messages problem. Any "right" to legally drop a message is a target of a primary concern, any chance to fall into a blocking state is the next one.